# AJAX Some questions

Tags: php, ajax

So I am very new to this concept.

So why not go headfirst :) Some things I don't understand;

What happens if js is disabled?

If using mysql databases (ie; checking forms and such) why not just use php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm what others have said, disabling Javascript will also disable the AJAX call.  After all, AJAX stands for "Asynchronous Javascript and XML".

---

To address why you can't just use PHP, there are some things that just can't be done without it.  PHP is great to load the page with the initial information, but after the page is loaded, it actually requires the page to be reloaded to load something else. AJAX allows you to get around this hassle.

For your example of form validation, AJAX can be used to validate the information while the person is filling it out.  Otherwise, you are required to reload the page each time someone fills out another field in the form.

Another example is from a project that I have worked on.  The form required a zip code and would load the appropriate city and county based on the inputted zip.  Using strict PHP, I would need the client to download the entire zip table embedded in the HTML/JS (which would add another 100k at least to the download).

Using AJAX, I can get around this.  The user can input the zip code, which triggers an AJAX call that downloads the few rows that I need (this will be less than a few hundred bytes, for comparison).

[Edit:] Also, a tip because you said that you were new to AJAX.  If your dealing with some form of authentication (logging in, etc.), remember to validate the user on the AJAX pages themselves.  Otherwise, tricky users will be able to access sensitive information for your database.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax just adds to the user experience and allows a web application to feel more like a desktop application to users. So they can delete a record and stay on the same page without reloading, you just let the record disappear.

And remember to validate on the server-side, even if you validate on client-side. Your weakest at your client-side as someone can easily just submit the values straight to your script so ALWAYS check on the server-side and do client-side if you would like to add some nice effects etc.

But you will always need to keep in mind that there are people out there who have javascript disable be it a security policy or just because their paranoid. So when you don't have JS enabled you javascript and AJAX requests won't work. So while developing you will need to make sure that if javascript is not their to do the operation that the form is submitted just like a normal HTTP form, this will allow all those paranoid people to also use your application :D.

OR you could always just deny access to those who don't have Javascript enabled but that's not very nice ... So if you want to check if they have javascript enabled checkout - http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp - for a example.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a Javascript client based technology. If js is disable it simply doesn't work. 
Php is a server based technology.

In Php you write pages that are dinamically built **by the server**. Once built they are sent as html to the client.

Using javascript (and Ajax) you can call the server just to request some datas (hint: look at JSON) or just a little html snippet which is *plugged* in the current page directly by the browser without requesting a full refresh from the server.

With js and AJAX you can achieve a very rich client experience without reloading a full page every time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe nothing will happen if js is disabled. You need js to grab the data.

If you want to use mysql databases, you can use js to access a php script, which can then return any data gathered from a database, rather than doing it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a way for Javascript (client side) to access PHP/ASP/Whatever serverside language you are using. This means, that if you have an PHP script for getting some data from your MySQL database, and want to run that script when the user clicks some random button, AJAX can do that (async)m and you wont have to reload you page to execute the PHP script.
If Javascript is diabled, AJAX won't work.